# Library of regular expressions for lexical relations in a corpus

Tags: computational-linguistics, corpora, resource-request, lexical-relations

I would like to ask if there is a library of regular expressions for mining patterns reflecting lexical semantic relations from a corpus.
These patterns should cover a wide variety of aspects synonymy ("A is a B", "A a.k.a B", "A sometimes called B", ...), hyponymy, and so on.
This could be quite interesting for me, since instead of relying in the mere co-occurence of words in a corpus, I could rely in the existence of patterns assuring the accuracy of the semantic relation.

Comment: What kind of research did you do already? Pattern based *Information extraction* is established for quite some time, and there are easily available publications on that topic.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. You are right. However, most of authors use just a dozen of patterns, and moreover, they describe them using plain language instead of the corresponding regular expressions. Such a library could help me to save a lot of time (and errors) on manually coding all the possible regular expressions. Best regards